# Why is $(z^2-x^2y, y^2-xz, x^3-yz)$ a prime ideal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

How can I prove that the ideal $I = (z^2-x^2y, y^2-xz, x^3-yz)$ is a prime ideal of $ K[x,y,z]$. I want to construct a morphism $\phi:K[x,y,z] \rightarrow K[t,s]$ whose kernel is equal to $I$ but from the picture I just don't see a parametrization or how to do it.

Comment: Which picture?.

Comment: If you plot the zero locus, I was trying to guess a parametrization...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think an explanation of where lhf got those numbers would be helpful. I am going to create a matrix in which each row corresponds to one of the generating binomials. Each column will be associated to $x,y,$ and $z$ respectively. An exponent before the minus sign will result in a positive entry and an exponent after the minus sign will correspond to a negative entry.

For instance: $z^2 - x^2y$ will correspond to the row $\begin{pmatrix}-2 & -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$.

So the matrix we get from this ideal is:

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
-2 & -1 & 2 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\
3 & -1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}_.$$

Now if we define a morhpism $\varphi : K[x,y,z] \to K[t]$ by $\varphi(x) = t^a$, $\varphi(y) = t^b$, and $\varphi(z) = t^c$; then $I$ will be the kernel precisely when $$\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix}$$ is in the kernel of $A$.

It happens that $\ker(A)$ is spanned by $$\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}_.$$

Disclaimer: When I said "precisely when", that statement takes a bit of proof. As lhf pointed out, one inclusion is obvious. The other might take a bit of work to convince yourself.

Comment: Disclosure: I [asked WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=kernel+%5B%5B-2,-1,2%5D,%5B-1,2,-1%5D,%5B3,-1,-1%5D%5D) to give me the kernel of the matrix and it gave me the span of (3,4,5). :p

Answer (score 1):

Try $\phi: K[x,y,z] \rightarrow K[t]$ with $\phi(x)=t^3$, $\phi(y)=t^4$, $\phi(z)=t^5$.

It is immediate that $I \subseteq \ker \phi$. I haven't checked the reverse inclusion.

Comment: Disclosure: I [asked WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%5E2-x%5E2y%3D0,+y%5E2-xz%3D0,+x%5E3-yz%3D0) to solve $z^2-x^2y=0, y^2-xz=0, x^3-yz=0$ and got $y = x^{4/3}, z = x^{5/3}$. So I set $t= x^{1/3}$.

Comment: Disclosure: I [asked WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=kernel+%5B%5B-2,-1,2%5D,%5B-1,2,-1%5D,%5B3,-1,-1%5D%5D) to give me the kernel of the matrix and it gave me the span of (3,4,5). :p